# ¿Does a RAID array persist through multiple OS installations?

Tags: hard-drive, raid, software-raid, hardware-raid

As title said; i'd like to know if a Windows-made software RAID array will persist a new installation, if I could read that RAID with another Windows partition or installation and if other OS could read that RAID array (assuming Linux-based OS could read NTFS KEKW).

I'd also like to know if a BIOS-made software RAID array could be read in that same way and, if possible, any documentation in how to do it. Lastly, if a hardware RAID array could be made and read by any OS or if it would depend of the partition that hardware RAID array had.

If needed, my PC specs are: x570 motherboard and SATA/NVMe m.2 drives.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two kinds of RAID:

- Hardware RAID, requiring a RAID I/O controller hub (ICH) and firmware
- Software RAID, done in the operating system

A hardware RAID is usually created before the operating system is installed
on it (although in most cases this can also be done afterward).
This RAID is created independently from the operating system and the two are
quite distinct. The OS will treat it as one disk and doesn't need to know
anything more about it (although it can).

A software RAID is created by the operating system, in effect emulating
via software the hardware RAID.
It can survive an operating system upgrade, but not
a total reinstall that erases and replaces the OS that created the RAID.

To answer the question: If you have created the RAID via the BIOS,
this is then a hardware RAID.

Useful references:

- [Hardware vs Software RAID: The Advantages, Disadvantages, and How to Choose](https://getprostorage.com/blog/hardware-vs-software-raid/)
- [Software RAID vs Hardware RAID: The Advantages and Disadvantages](https://www.dataplugs.com/en/software-raid-vs-hardware-raid-advantages-disadvantages/)